# Running a command behind BASH prompt in bashrc

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start background process from .bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065954/start-background-process-from-bashrc)

I'm executing a script in .bashrc and the user prompt will not appear until all commands have executed. Is there a way, on launching a terminal, that the prompt appears while the commands execute in the background?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append `&` to your command to have it run in the background.

Comment: I have an & at the end of the command but it's still echoing to the terminal. if i run the command and &>/dev/null I don't see an echo, but the user's prompt won't appear until after the command has executed, which is several seconds. Is there a way around that?

Comment: oh, you didn't say you wanted to hide the output of the background commands.  try putting the ampersand after the commmand and stdout/stderr redirect, like this:  `/usr/bin/command &>/dev/null &`

Comment: and *that* is a beautiful thing. thank you for the assist!