# suspend/resume a process started from ~/.bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, server

I want to start a long-running python process when I log-in to a server.
So I  put something like this into ~/.bashrc

```
python long_running_process.py
```

This correctly starts the python process on login. The problem here is that I'm not able to suspend it later (with ctrl-z). I can only exit the process by presssing ctrl-c.

I'd like to be able to pause/suspend and resume the python process if possible. This is different from "backgrounding" the process which has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065954/start-background-process-from-bashrc)

EDIT: I found a hack that kindof works. I create a dummy shell-script called ~/run.sh and make it executable. Then I put

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
python long_running_process.py
```

in ~/run.sh.

Lastly, I call ~/run.sh in ~/.bashrc instead of starting the python process directly. Giving `set -m` enables job-control in the script (which is disabled by default for shell-scripts it seems)

This is **very** hacky. If someone has a nicer/cleaner solution, I'd be very interested in hearing it

Comment: try running the process by giving it executing permissions and executing it by its absolute name. That'd work I suppose...
`<path_to_file>/long_running_process.py`

Comment: It doesn't seem to. I tried something simpler. I put `#!/bin/bash\n sleep 10s` in ~/run,made ~run executable and added `source $HOME/run` to ~/.bashrc. But the `sleep` process is not suspendable. I can only exit it with ctrl-c

Comment: How does ".bashrc" continue to run - does thew process keeps itself in the foreground ? does the process put itself into the background (with a fork()), or is it placed into a background job (python ... &) ?

Comment: `kill` with SIGSTOP and continue with `SIGCONT` maybe?

Comment: This is the last "thing" started by ~/.bashrc. So the rest of the stuff to be done by ~/bashrc is already over by the time the python job starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use POSIX signals, sent with the `kill` command. I'll run this little Python script that prints its `process id` and the time once per second, then pause it then resume it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time

while True:
    print(f"Process id: {os.getpid()}, time: {int(time.time())}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

It started with `process id` 63070, so I can pause it with:

```
kill -STOP 63070
```

and then resume it with:

```
kill -CONT 63070
```

[image]

Comment: both mark and zig razor give the right answer. But I'm accepting mark's since its more detailed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the process with command `kill -SIGSTOP pid` where pid is the process id (you can find it with command `ps -ef | grep process_name` ) and then continue the process with signal **SIGCONT**.